# WPF - Allow application to be searched using a name different than .exe name

Tags: wpf, advanced-installer

We're planning to change the name of our WPF application. However, we'd want our users to be able to search the application (from windows search) using the old name as well.

For example, old name = Sample.exe & new name = Test.exe. If I type Sample in the windows search, it should show the new application Test.exe. Is this possible?  We use Advanced Installer for deploying our app.

Comment: You could try adding a shortcut in the program folder with the old name that points to the exe with the new name,

Comment: That was a good suggestion but unfortunately I forgot to tell you that the application logo is changing as well. Is it possible to do something using Advanced Installer ?

Comment: Do you want the oldName.exe to have the same logo as newName.exe, or a different one?  If a shortcut isn't acceptable at all, you could create a small stand alone exe with whatever name and icon you want, and have it do nothing but launch the new exe.  The installer could place both applications.

Comment: I was thinking about adding the old name in comments of the shortcut properties but unfortunately it doesn't work